# How plasma ball works?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, plasma-physics

I am always confused with the concept of earthing in electricity. I have read and done few experiments and I understand that electricity needs to close the circuit. I can understand that from the context of a battery.

But what I am confused always is about earthing. From a battery we can see that the electrons can flow from the negative terminal to the positive terminal to close the circuit.

From that analogy I am unable to understand how a plasma ball works. When I read about it, the explanation given is that the electrons will flow through your body to the earth when you touch it. How does that help to complete the circuit?

I am also unable to understand the earthing in household electricity. What I have read and probably misunderstood is that the Earth is a big capacitor which can store charges. But even then how does it help to complete the circuit in the above two examples like plasma ball or household earthing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that "plasma ball" means [these things](https://www.amazon.com.au/Gresus-Size-Magic-Plasma-Ball/dp/B086ZJQ8BR/ref=asc_df_B086ZJQ8BR/?tag=bingshopdesk-22&linkCode=df0&hvadid=&hvpos=&hvnetw=s&hvrand=&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=e&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=&hvtargid=pla-4584138868270156&psc=1)

"the electrons will flow through your body to the earth when you touch it"

That works because the plasma ball is itself connected to earth (via the power cord), so there is a closed circuit when you touch the ball. A current can only flow if there is a continuous circuit from one power terminal to the other.

In general earthing is used in mains power circuits, to give the current a return path without going through your body, as that could be fatal. With AC equipment, earthing is also used to keep the equipment at a constant voltage level, in order to reduce induced 50Hz hum. If the equipment is battery-powered, earthing is not normally required as there are no high voltages with respect to ground. Even if the equipment generates a high voltage internally, that is not dangerous, unless the current can flow through you.

If proper precautions are used, it is quite safe to touch equipment at a potential of thousands of volts above ground. Just make sure your body cannot become part of a closed circuit, by insulating yourself from ground. Alternatively, make certain that the current through your body will be very small - it's the current that kills, not the voltage.

Comment: Even if I understood what you meant, voltage is the force that makes current flow, so I find your last statement misleading. Also, if you body is under a potential difference and we neglect the damage a current flowing through you will do (electrons collisioning with your atoms) you will still get hurt because your personal electrons will escape from their atoms.

Comment: Yes plasma ball is the same thing you mentioned. So are you saying that one terminal of that plasma ball is connected to the earth through household wiring?

Comment: "It's the current that kills, not the voltage." is only true when you ensure that even though there is a high voltage there is a tiny current (which was made semi-clear in your post). In general, this requirement is not met, and so the statement will not be true. (for this reason, we see "high voltage" danger signs instead of "high current" signs)

Comment: @SRaj yes, some part of the plasma ball is connected to ground. Even if it is via some high resistance instead of a wire, some current will flow back to ground. Without a closed circuit there can be no current.

Comment: Are you sure about the plasma ball explanation? My son just bought one of them and it's battery powered. No return path I can see. And my finger has a significant effect with even a 1cm air gap.

Answer (score 1):

The streams of plasma are seeking a load. If properly built, the center electrode sees more-or-less the same impedance to each point on the globe. When you touch the globe, you lower the impedance at that spot because you are a capacitive load. No electrons flow through the glass, your square yard of flesh is a big, wet electrode in a big damp world. You don't glow, you're not excitable in that way, but you can feel the most minute tingle as the potential on your capacitive plate (skin) interacts with the air around you.